# Get the data from the console

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get all the data from the console to a variable without stopping her work.

```
console.log=function(e){alert(e)}
```

I tried to get a log from the console but they disappeared from the console. It is even possible? Is it possible to get all data, not for only **.log**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would have to keep a copy of the old `console.log()` method and call it again from your custom implementation:

```
(function(o) {
    // keep old log method
    var _log = o.log;

    o.log = function(e) {
        alert(e);
        _log.call(o, e);
    }

}(console));
```

Comment: Is it possible to all data, not for only .log?

Comment: @Aleksov Yeah, you could "reroute" any function that way :)

Comment: how to implement it in practice?

Comment: @Aleksov You would implement it exactly as I've shown, but for each method that you wish to route.

Comment: @Jack OK! It seems I understand what you mean! Thank you again!